# SSRS BIDS changing the meta tag

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

When developing reports using SSRS BIDS/SQL Server 2008 R2 is there anyway you can alter the metatag or css used for the report.

I want to add this to the header of the report part in question:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was also trying to find an official way to achieve that but this far I haven't been successful. My hack way, that seems to get the job done, is to update the file *ReportViewer.aspx* located under the path below.

> Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\Pages

Just add the meta tag to head section.